# "detail": "JSON parse error - Extra data: line 1 column 9 (char 8)" in django rest framework post request

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Here is my view

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def afficher_donnees_instantanees(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.data)
        deveui = request.data["deveui"]
        donnees = Historique.objects.filter(infos_signal__machine=deveui, infos_signal__jour=datetime.today()).order_by("-id").first()
        serializer = HistoriqueSerializer(donnees)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    else:
        return Response({"echec": "echec"})

serializer.py
class HistoriqueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Historique
        fields = '__all__'
```

I want to display data from my **Historique** model in response to a POST request, but I get the message "**JSON parse error - Extra data: line 1 column 9 (char 8)**".
Knowing that the **response code is 400**. Where can this error come from please?

Comment: This sometimes happens when the json request body that are passing to the endpoint has a typo. Check comma separators